# Drupal / phpMyAdmin Issue

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, phpmyadmin

Came across a weird issue today.

Have a Drupal site, been live for a few years now, and this is actually the first time I've had to look at anything with it.

I needed to check out one of the tables in the MySQL database, anything I select for it throws a `500 Server Error` popup, but does not do this for all tables.

I thought maybe a `repair` would do, but of course InnoDB doesn't support that, so I am at a loss to what the issue could be, and how I can get into this table to view/manually modify some records.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This does not seem like  drupal question to me. Is the site running ok?

Comment: I only assume it's drupal because it's a drupal site.  As far as it running ok, it does run ok... other than being a dog

Comment: How are you selecting a table from the database?

Comment: clicking the table in PMA

Comment: Well it does not seem to be a drupal problem then. Have you tried using the mysql in the console rather than phpmyadmin?